# replace complex string with sed

Tags: bash, replace, sed

Trying to find and replace `PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "` with something like:
 `PS1='\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '` in `/etc/bashrc` file with sed has been failed because of two levels of interpretion: bash and sed iteself.

How should I replace those complex strings using bash and sed?

Comment: What do you mean by `two levels of interpretion` ? The only problem i could see you having is using both types of quotes inside your sed. But you can get round this by just putting it in a script file.

Comment: I mean there is characters that should be escaped from bash and characters that should be escaped from sed in that command and when I execute that command in BASH in made the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built the expression piece by piece, up to the following:

```
sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\\\$ "/PS1='\''\\[\\e[0;31m\\][\\u@\\h \\W]\\$\\[\\e[m\\] '\'/
```

Here are some of the steps:

```
echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed s/a/b/)
           <(PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')

echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[//')
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')


echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h//')
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')

echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h \\W]//')
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')

echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\\\$ "//')
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')
```

Here we are matching correctly the whole input, so we can start outputting:

```
echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\\\$ "/PS1='\''/')
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')

echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\\\$ "/PS1='\''\\[\\e/')
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')

echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\\\$ "/PS1='\''\\[\\e[0;31m\\][\\u@\\h \\W]\\$\\[\\e[m\\] /')
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')

echo 'PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "' \
    | diff <(sed 's/PS1="\[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\\\$ "/PS1='\''\\[\\e[0;31m\\][\\u@\\h \\W]\\$\\[\\e[m\\] '\'/)
           <(echo PS1=\''\[\e[0;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[m\] '\')
```

Comment: That's eye-hurting :D