# change complex string with sed | grep

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I know this question will fall under duplicate. Among all the answers that I read, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264756/replace-complex-string-with-sed) one comes close to a solution but the answer is a little bit hard to understand.

So what I wanted to do is, I wanted to change a complex string with another value.

```
install_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}
```

This is the line that I want to replace with this:

```
install_command = pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}
```

Simply I tried this at first:

```
sed -i 's/\binstall_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}\b/install_command = pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}/' tox.ini
```

Then I tried this just to check:

```
grep -A 0 "install_command = " tox.ini | sed -i "s/install_command = */install_command = \${pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}}/
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
```

Advance thanks.

Comment: Don't use the `-i` option to `sed` until you know that the command you're executing makes the change you want.

Comment: Why did you added those `\b` in the beginning and ending? Just remove them.

Comment: To match the exact string I used `\b`

Comment: That's not what `\b` does; in the `sed` dialects where it is supported, it matches a word boundary (more specifically, a character position between two characters where one is alphabetic and the other is not, where beginning or end of string counts as nonalphabetic). But if it doesn't work for you, it quite likely matches a literal `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` command does the job:

```
sed -e '/:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:/ s%-c{[^}]*}%-c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt%'
```

It looks for a line that contains the string `UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE` between two colons.  On any such line that it finds, it replaces the `-c{…}` part with the desired replacement text, using the `s%%%` command with `%` in place of `/` to avoid the conflict with the `/` in the replacement text.  The pattern `-c{[^}]*}` matches `-c` followed by a `{`, a sequence of characters other than `}`, and finally `}`.  Note that if you enable extended regular expressions (usually `-r` or `-E`), you have to handle `{` and `}` as metacharacters and escape them with a backslash.  Some (probably most) versions of `sed` do not recognize `\b` as a word boundary — the regular expressions recognized by `sed` are quite limited.

Given input line:

```
install_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}
```

it produces the output line:

```
install_command = pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}
```

You can tweak the script in many ways, especially making the 'selection condition' more precise if that's necessary (if there are other lines which contain matching text).

Comment: Wonderfully explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is good enough, just do not add `\b` on beginning and use a different regex separator, for example `~`, because you want to replace strings with `/` inside them:

```
$ echo  'install_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}' | 
> sed 's~install_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}~install_command = pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}~
install_command = pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}
```

But there's no need to match *everything*, just match you need:

```
$ echo 'install_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}' |
> sed 's~{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens}~{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt~'
install_command = pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}
```

but really, simplify this, match up until a `}`:

```
$ echo 'install_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}' |
> sed 's~-c{[^}]*}~-c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt~'
install_command = pip install -c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt {opts} {packages}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. 
I am new at this so, to access the file I should use grep ? Then use the rest of the command ?
`grep 'install_command = pip install -c{env:UPPER_CONSTRAINTS_FILE:https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/queens} {opts} {packages}' tox.ini |
> sed 's~-c{[^}]*}~-c{toxinidir}/upper-constraints.txt~'`

Comment: @ishmam999 — no, you probably shouldn't use `grep` here.  It depends on how many lines are in the original file and whether you want the one line changed while the others are unchanged or whether you want to extract the one line and edit it to create a new line.  However, `sed` can select the right line and munge it; you have options like `-n` to suppress the normal printing cycle, and you can add `p` after a `s///` command to print the result, overriding the `-n` option.  Etc.  But `sed` can do the gripping for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$ cat change_txt.txt |sed 's/env.*plain/toxinidir}/;s/?h.*/ {opts} {packages}/'
```

Where I put your string in "change_txt.txt" file.
I know there is better solution, but now I managed to get result using this one.

Comment: This does work.  The first `s///` command removes the material after the `{` by identifying the start as `env` up to the word `plain` and replacing it with the `toxinidir}`.  The second `s///` command replaces everything from the `?h` in `?h=stable` with the `{opts} {packages}`.  It is an interesting way of dissecting the input and output — not the one I'd choose, but it does work.